# CentOS7: How to start the slapd service in a docker container?

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, openldap

I want to run an OpenLDAP server in a docker container using CentOS7.
I managed to have a container running with an openldap installed in it. My problem is that I am using a script entrypoint.sh to start the slapd service and add a user to my directory. I would like this two steps to be in the Dockerfile so that the password to perform ldapadd is not stored in the script.

So far I have only found examples on debian .
https://github.com/kanboard/docker-openldap/blob/master/memberUid/Dockerfile this is what I would like to do but using CentOS 7.
I tried start slapd service in my Dockerfile without success.

My Dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install \
openldap-servers \
openldap-clients \
libselinux-python \
openssl \
; yum clean all

RUN chown ldap:ldap -R /var/lib/ldap
COPY slapd.conf /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
COPY base.ldif /etc/openldap/schema/base.ldif
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 500 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

My entrypoint.sh script looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

exec /usr/sbin/slapd -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -h "ldapi:/// ldap:///" -d stats &
sleep 10
ldapadd -x -w mypassword -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=mydomain" -f /etc/openldap/schema/base.ldif
```

This does work however I am looking to start the ldap service and do the ldapadd command in the Dockerfile not to have mypassword stored in entrypoint.sh.
Hence I tried these commands :

```
RUN systemctl slapd start
RUN ldapadd -x -w password -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=mydomain" -f /etc/openldap/schema/base.ldif
```

Of course this does not work as systemctl does not work in Dockerfile. What is the best alternative ? I was considering having one container starting the ldap servcie but then I do not know how to call it to build the image of the other container...

EDIT :

Thanks to Guido U. Draheim, I have an alternative to systemctl to start slapd service.

My Dockerfile now looks like this :

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install \
openldap-servers \
openldap-clients \
libselinux-python \
openssl \
; yum clean all
RUN chown ldap:ldap -R /var/lib/ldap
COPY slapd.conf /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
COPY base.ldif /etc/openldap/schema/base.ldif
COPY files/docker/systemctl.py /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN systemctl enable slapd
RUN systemctl start slapd;\
    ldapdd -x -w password -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=sblanche" -f /etc/openldap/schema/base.ldif
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 500 /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

But I have got the following error : ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Answer (score 1):

(a) you could use the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) to run your "systemctl.py start slapd". Which is the obvious first error.

(b) each RUN in a dockerfile is a new container, so the running process from the earlier invocation can not survive anyway. That's why the referenced dockerfile example has it combined with "&&".

And yeah (c) I am using an openldap centos container. So go ahead, try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help however the Dockerfile seems to block at the command RUN systemctl start slapd which is weird because if I do not use this run but enter the container and start the service manually it works.

Comment: I have the following message :
Step 5/11: RUN systemctl start slapd
----> Running in 00678FC4948a
slapd.servic: tlsmc_get_pin: INFO: Please note the extracted key file will not be protected with a PIN anymore, howerver it will be still protected at leat by file permissions